# read vs map in ghci

Tags: haskell, ghci

I tried the following in ghci 7.6.3

`prelude> let m = map`

The above works. No errors from GHCi.

But then I tried,

`prelude> let r = read`

The above code throws a big fat error in GHCi. And this is the error I get,

```
*Main> let r = read

<interactive>:122:9:
    No instance for (Read a0) arising from a use of `read'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Read IOMode -- Defined in `GHC.IO.IOMode'
      instance Read BufferMode -- Defined in `GHC.IO.Handle.Types'
      instance Read Newline -- Defined in `GHC.IO.Handle.Types'
      ...plus 30 others
    In the expression: read
    In an equation for `r': r = read
```

And then I tried,

`prelude> let r = read :: Read a => String -> a`

thinking the type signature might fix things. But then again, I got an error from GHCi. The exact error is as follows,

```
*Main> let r = read :: Read a => String -> a

<interactive>:123:9:
    No instance for (Read a0) arising from an expression type signature
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Read IOMode -- Defined in `GHC.IO.IOMode'
      instance Read BufferMode -- Defined in `GHC.IO.Handle.Types'
      instance Read Newline -- Defined in `GHC.IO.Handle.Types'
      ...plus 30 others
    In the expression: read :: Read a => String -> a
    In an equation for `r': r = read :: Read a => String -> a
*Main>
```

Could someone please tell me what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: You've run into the monomorphism restriction.
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction

Comment: Pro tip: include the "big fat error" in the problem report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an example of the monomorphism restriction. By default, you aren't allowed to bind polymorphic values like that because it looks like the value of `r` should only be computed once, but it is actually recomputed every time it is called.

In this case, `read` is polymorphic because it has an implicit parameter for passing the dictionary for the `Read` typeclass, so `r` needs to be recomputed each time. `map` is monomorphic, because it doesn't have any typeclass restrictions.

If you instead write it as

```
let r x = read x
```

it will be allowed.

You can also add a non-polymorphic type signature:

```
let r = read :: String -> Int
```

This allows it to compute `r` a single time for a single instance of `Read`.

Normal declarations with a type signature are also exempt from the monomorphism restriction, so it you write it like this it will be allowed.

```
r :: Read a => String -> a
r = read
```

You can also simply turn off the monomorphism restriction using the `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` option or adding `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` to the top of the file. It is generally considered safe to do this, though it can have a negative performance impact.

Comment: This does not explain why `let m = map` works nor does it take into account that the monomorphism restriction does not apply to variables that have a type signature (which the OP tried to make use of, but he added the type signature at the wrong place).

Comment: If i had added a non-polymorphic type signature, at the same place, it would have still worked.